# How can I get rid of these jagged lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anti-aliasing

[image]

I am trying to create a box shape using pen tool but its looks jagged, and when  I save this image its looks very rough. How can I fix this kind of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this in illustrator/export, but the problem you're having is called *aliasing*. You want to look for terms like `adobe illustrator export anti-aliasing`.

Comment: I'm looking at this picture from a mobile device, so I can't quite see if the lack of anti-aliasing is an issue here. But from what I can see, there seems to be some background peaking from between the surfaces. You should make sure there isn't a gap there.

Comment: The most problem occurs when i copy the vector and paste as smart object into Photoshop. It looks very jagged There.

Answer (score 2):

When you place the AI file in Photoshop, Photoshop must *render* the vector file as a raster image. The aliasing will be lessened if you have more pixels available between the endpoints.

In short, you will probably have better results if the pixel dimensions of the Photoshop document are larger. If you have the document set to the final target size, you might experiment with a copy of the file which is twice the size and then reduce the pixel dimensions during "save for web" or export.